# Find all sets (vectors) who satisfy some conditions

Tags: c#, c, parallel-processing

I am searching for solution of this problem. I have the length of the set (n), the sum of the set, and the maximum value k that can be some element in the set.

For example, n=5, k=3, sum=10

The code should return some of these sets [3, 3, 2, 1, 1]; [3, 2, 2, 2, 1]

How to find these sets pragmatically in c, c#?

Comment: Please add practical task that leads to this problem to your question. So far it feels like "will you do my homework"... Also explain in what way you want to parallelize the process.

Comment: post the program , you have worked on till now...

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution from my answer in Java:

```
public class Main {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
private static void printVectors(int[] p, int n) {

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.print(p[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
//main function
private static void computeVectors(int[] n, int sum, int k, int k1, int i) {


    if (sum == 0) {

        printVectors(n, n.length);
    } else if (i < n.length) {

        for (int j = k; j >= 0; j--) {

            if (j <= k1) {
                n[i] = j;
                computeVectors(n, sum - j, sum - j, k1, i + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    computeVectors(new int[5], 10, 3, 3, 0);

}
```

}

Some of the output of the program if n=5; sum=10; k=3 is:

3 1 2 2 2

3 1 2 1 3

3 1 1 3 2

3 1 1 2 3

3 1 0 3 3

3 0 3 3 1

3 0 3 2 2

3 0 3 1 3

3 0 2 3 2

3 0 2 2 3

3 0 1 3 3

2 3 3 2 0

2 3 3 1 1

2 3 3 0 2

2 3 2 3 0

As you can see computeVectors is recursive function, the question is, can this function be implemented without recursion, I tried with the code below but it is not working:

```
private static void computeVectorsNoRecursion(int[] n, int sum, int k, int i) {
    if (sum == 0) {

        printVectors(n, n.length);
    } else if (i < n.length) {
        int j=k;
       // for (int j = k; j >= 0; j--) {

            while (j <= k) {
                if(j>=0)
                {
                n[i]=j;
                i++;
              int temp=sum;
                sum=temp-j;
                k=temp-j;
                j--;
                if(i>=n.length)
                {
                    i=0;
                    printVectors(n, n.length);
                }

            }
        }

      //  }
    }
}
```